# Problems in Visual studio 2019 16.11.3

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have update visual studio since two days. Now when I write any code it's stop writing suddenly or write in reverse mode, for example (null become llun). Also, the code is moving right and left and add spacing at some points, and ctrl+Z does not work and fix these problems, also suddenly I can't select text, or lines become overlapped so I can't read code correctly.
Any one have this problems? and how I can fix it? and if there is not any solve to this problem how I can return to previous edition?

Edit:
I want fix problem first, but if that impossible I will search for downgrade version.

Edit: I uninstall resharper then install it again, then every thing work correctly.